# Git manage a portion of code to another repo

Tags: git, github

I have the following situation:
My code base folder has two subfolders:

- main_code
- experiments

Right now, only the code inside main_code is tracked added and committed. There is also a remote ("origin") to a external repository.

What I want to do is to put all the code in *experiments* (that is not tracked now) in another external repository. How can I do that?

I was thinking of adding another remote (other than "origin"), say experiment_repo, but if I do that, how can I put *only* the code in experiments in said repo?

EDIT: Just to clarify:

`main_code` annd `experiments` are subfolders of `base_folder` and `.git` is in the `base_folder` .

Answer (score 1):

If your repository is in `main_code` (meaning there is a `main_code/.git` subfolder), and experiments is not yet in a repository, all you need to do is (since no part of experiments have been staged, tracked or committed):

```sh
cd base_folder
mv experiments ..
cd ../experiments
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "Import experiments code"
git remote add origin https://github.com/new/empty/repository
git push -u origin main
```

You could [install](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) and then use the `gh` CLI tool, and create your remote repository with [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) (after a [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) first).

Comment: my problem is that `.git` is in the base folder, not in `main_code`  :(

Comment: @KansaiRobot Did you already add and commit experiment in that repository? If yes, do you need all the history of that folder in your new repository?

Comment: No,no part of experiments have been staged, tracked or commited.

Comment: @KansaiRobot OK then. I have updated my answer accordingly.